# R: Time series correlogram lag value

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

I am completely new to time series and trying to understand correlograms.

For `acf` function, there is a `lag.max` value.
How do you determine the value of `lag.max` of the data?
Is there a formula or a rule for this?

Comment: As stated in the help file, this is just the maximum lag for which you want acf to be calculated. Its going to calculate autocorrelation for each lag from 0 to lag.max. You can just use the default rule of thumb already available within the function when you do not supply.

Answer (score 1):

> As stated in the help file, this is just the maximum lag for which you want acf to be calculated. Its going to calculate autocorrelation for each lag from 0 to lag.max. You can just use the default rule of thumb already available within the function when you do not supply.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @A.Webb as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.